# How to get Woocommerce Product Gallery image URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a wordpress woo commerce shopping site and added some products. i want to get the product gallery image urls of each products.

[image: screen shot of product page]

how can I get the URLs of images?

Comment: hey dude. i want urls dynamically

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    global $product;

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    }
?>
```

Comment: hi gaurav, its getting featured image url, i want the URLs of product gallery images.

Comment: please check now and let me know.

Comment: only geting one image url

Comment: It's getting all image url..i have just checked.

Comment: get_gallery_attachment_ids() is obsolet now it's get_gallery_image_ids()

Comment: A more up to date solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277465/getting-the-gallery-images-from-products-in-woocommerce/311359#311359